# How to use key/value pairs in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a simple code to read a text file.  Here's a snippet:

```
linestring = open(wFile, 'r').read()

# Split on line Feeds
lines = linestring.split('\n')

num = len(lines)
print num

numHeaders = 18

proc = lines[0]
header = {}
for line in lines[1:18]:
    keyVal = line.split('=')
    header[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1]

    # note that the first member is {'Mode', '5'}        

    print header[keyVal[0]]   # this prints the number '5' correctly

    print header['Mode']    # this fails
```

This last print statement creates the runtime error:

```
    print header['Mode']
KeyError: 'Mode'
```

The first print statement `print header[keyVal[0]]` works fine but the second fails!!!  `keyVal[0]` IS the string literal `'Mode'`

Why does using the string `'Mode'` directly fail?

Comment: what do you get with `print header` .... often times a simple print helps you debug your problem ... what you are describing is not correct ... your dictionary does not look like you think it does (perhaps its `"  Mode"` or `"Mode   "`) you could also `print keyVal[0] == "Mode"`

Comment: `{'Mode', '5'}` is a `set` in Python >=2.7 and a syntax error in older Pythons. Did you mean `{'Mode': 5}`?

Comment: when I ask to print header I get, {'Mode ': ' 5'}

Comment: there is a space after the `e` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keyVal = map(str.strip,line.split('=')) #this will remove extra whitespace
```

you have whitespace problems ...

Answer (score 2):

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) with no arguments will split on all consecutive whitespace, so

```
'foo    bar'.split()
```

is `['foo', 'bar']`.

But if you give it an argument, it no longer removes whitespace for you, so

```
'foo   = bar'.split('=')
```

is `['foo   ', ' bar']`.

You need to clean up the whitespace yourself. One way to do that is using a list comprehension:

```
[s.strip() for s in orig_string.split('=')]
```

Comment: more in depth than my answer +1

Comment: Yes this works as well.  Joran's is more compact!  Thanks you!